# show that, $x^mf(u,x)= x^m \frac{e^{ux}}{e^x+1}$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}_0$ is lebesgue-integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:(0,1) \times \mathbb{R}$, by $f(u,x)= \frac{e^{ux}}{e^x+1}$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Show that:

$x \mapsto x^m f(u,x)$ is for $u \in (0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty,0]\cup[0,\infty)$ lebesgue-integrable.

I need some help for this exercise. I don't how to start... Would be the frist step to show that $f(u,x)= \frac{e^{ux}}{e^x+1}$ is lebesgue-integrable or should I begin with $x^m f(u,x)$?

And which theorems would be helpful to have a better understanding of the problem?

I appreciate any Hint and explanations I get.

Comment: It would suffice to show that the function is continuous.

Comment: @Math1000 it would not? Continuity implies that the function is measurable but he asks for integrable so showing that the integral on $\mathbb{R} $ of the absolute value with respect to $x$ is finite

Comment: I will assume that you want to show that for a fixed $u$, the function is integrable. If you also want continuity in $u$ it requires a bit more precision to apply classical theorems but the ideas are the same. Since $f(u,.)$ is continuous in $x$ it is integrable on a bounded interval. You must show that it is integrable at infinity, a way to do this is to show that the absolute value is bounded by a function which you already know is integrable. For this, it will be important that $u<1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I appreciate it a lot. I want show that it is integrable not continuity, but when I am done with the task , I will try to show continuity too. It will be a good exercise :).

Comment: yesterday I made a little progress and got a better understanding of the task. I have to show $\int_{\mathbb R}|x|^m\frac{e^{ux}}{e^x+1}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}|x|^m\frac{e^{ux}}{e^x+1}dx+\int_0^{\infty}|x|^m\frac{e^{ux}}{e^x+1}dx<\infty $   

Now I need a function so that $x \mapsto x^m f(u,x)$ is boundend by the function and got these results

$\int_0^{\infty}|x|^m\frac{e^{ux}}{e^x+1}dx<\int_0^{\infty}x^m\frac{e^{ux}}{e^x}dx=\int_0^{\infty}x^me^{-(1-u)x}dx$.

Comment: The next step is to compute the the integral by parts, but I am stuck here.
The thing what disturb me is $x^m$. I dont know how to handle it because of $m$ is arbitrary but fixed.